# Guardar Informacion especifica que se imprime por consola

Tags: c#, bucle-for, condiciones, porcentaje

Estoy escribiendo un codigo que es muy comun, el volado (cara o cruz o coin flip), en el codigo le pido al usuario que me diga cual es su eleccion cara o cruz, y luego le pido cuantas veces quiere que el sistema tire la moneda.

Cada vez que la moneda se tire el sistema imprimira el resultado por consola, y al final le dira al usuario cuantas veces acerto en su eleccion,

El incoveniente que tengo y donde estoy atorado es que he tratado muchas formas de guardar solo las veces que el ususario acerto, por ejemplo si eligio cara entonces solo quiero guardar las veces que salio cara, aqui les dejo el codigo que tengo hasta ahora,  donde correctCount es donde estoy atorado y quiero guardar ahi las veces que el usuario acerto, gracias de antemano.

```
using System;

namespace Del2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String headsOrTailsGuess;
            int numberOfFlips;
            int correctCount;
            Random CoinFlip = new Random();

            Console.Write("Welcome to the Heads or Tails game " +
                "\nGuess which side will show more times : Heads or Tails?  ");    
                
            headsOrTailsGuess = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("How many times would you like the coin to be flipped? ");

            numberOfFlips = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine());

            
            correctCount = numberOfFlips;


            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++)
            {

                int flip = CoinFlip.Next(0, 2);

                if (flip == 0 && headsOrTailsGuess == "Heads")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Head");
                } 
                
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tail");
                }

               

            }

            int percentage = correctCount / numberOfFlips * 100;

            Console.WriteLine( "Your guess, " + headsOrTailsGuess + ", came up "  + correctCount + " time (s) \nThat's " + percentage + "%");
            Console.ReadLine();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es asignar el valor de la respuesta en un entero, para luego compararlo con el resultado del random. Te dejo un ejemplo

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String headsOrTailsGuess;
        int numberOfFlips;
        int userInput;
        int correctCount;
        Random CoinFlip = new Random();

        Console.Write("Welcome to the Heads or Tails game " +
            "\nGuess which side will show more times : Heads or Tails?  ");

        headsOrTailsGuess = Console.ReadLine();

        //aqui das el valor a la respuesta
        if (headsOrTailsGuess == "Heads") {
            userInput = 0;
        }
        else {
            userInput = 1;
        }

        Console.Write("How many times would you like the coin to be flipped? ");

        numberOfFlips = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        correctCount = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++)
        {

            int flip = CoinFlip.Next(0, 2);

            //comparas el resultado del random con la respuesta del usuario
            if (flip == userInput)
            {
                correctCount++;
            }
        }

        decimal percentage = (decimal)correctCount / numberOfFlips * 100;

        Console.WriteLine("Your guess, " + headsOrTailsGuess + ", came up " + correctCount + " time (s) \nThat's " + percentage + "%");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, todo funciona perfecto ahora!